# Cross-platform mySQL inconsistencies with character sets

Tags: c++, mysql, encoding

I have a script that creates a database, couple of tables in it and populates the data. This script was made from the SQLite database on Windows. One of the tables in that script is named "abcß" ("abc+ALT225").

Next I tried to load this script to mySQL thru mySQL Workbench. Both server and Workbench are running on Linux.

After fixing some syntax inconsistencies the database was successfully created. I tried to query the database and tables. All tables were queried successfully, but the one above.

Trying to query the "information_table.tables.table_name", I get that name as "abc\0d-61\0d63" which gives different result than the original name. Because of this my program is crashing when I run it because I sent the table name to codecvt_utf-8 encoder.

The database and tables are created with the default encoding.

Does anybody know why I'm not seeing the proper results?

But most importantly - I presume the program is crashing because some of the characters are outside of wchar_t/utf-8 encoding. So I'm curious - what should I use to convert that sequence to std::wstring?

TIA!

---

EDIT:

The code is as follows:

```
class MySQLDatabase
{
public:
    int LoadDatabaseData();
protected:
     struct MySQLImpl;
     MySQLImpl *m_pimpl;
};

struct MySQLDatabase::MySQLImpl
{
   std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t> > m_myconv;
};

int MySQLDatabase::LoadDatabaseData()
{
    const char *table_name;
    std::wstring tableName = m_pimpl->m_myconv.from_bytes( table_name );
}
```

---

EDIT2:

Do you think it will work if I add:

```
   std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t> > m_myconv;
```

?

---

EDIT3:

Here is what I see in the Workbench:

```
# TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, TABLE_TYPE, ENGINE, VERSION, ROW_FORMAT, TABLE_ROWS, AVG_ROW_LENGTH, DATA_LENGTH, MAX_DATA_LENGTH, INDEX_LENGTH, DATA_FREE, AUTO_INCREMENT, CREATE_TIME, UPDATE_TIME, CHECK_TIME, TABLE_COLLATION, CHECKSUM, CREATE_OPTIONS, TABLE_COMMENT
'def', 'draft', 'abcÃ', 'BASE TABLE', 'InnoDB', '10', 'Compact', '0', '0', '16384', '0', '0', '0', NULL, '2016-12-09 00:15:27', NULL, NULL, 'utf8_general_ci', NULL, '', ''
```

Comment: UTF-8 is compatible with `char`, that's the whole point of using it instead of UTF-16. It should be safe to use `std::string` with UTF-8 instead of going all complicated with `std::wstring` conversions.

Comment: @Havenard, the program is cross-platform and so it should run on Windows as well. AFAIK, Windows is UTF-16 platform.

Comment: Not really, all Windows APIs that take strings have a version for `char` and a version for `wchar_t`. Visual Studio will try to push use of wide char by default, but you can totally tell it to piss off in the project settings.

Comment: @Havenard It's best not to mess with the default Unicode project settings -- just avoid using TCHAR and convert UTF-8 chars to UTF-16 WCHARs when calling Win32 functions.

Comment: @Havenard, please read carefully!!! Project should be cross-platform and can be run on all 3 major platforms - Windows, *nix and Mac. It just MSVC is best when it comes to debugging/memory leaks.

Comment: @Havenard,question edited. Will it work in this case?

Comment: @MrEricSir, question edited. Will it work in this case?

Comment: Hard to say from this example; I would point out that wide strings mean something completely different on Linux and Mac than they do on Windows.

Comment: @MrEricSir, ok, so what is this characters - -6163d? Which encoding is it? Is it really UTF-16?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use utf-16 for anything.

Do not use "unicode".

Where the heck did `\0d-61` come from?

Do not use any conversion subroutines, go back to the source and make sure it is encoded UTF-8.

For verifying that you are using UTF-8, `abcß` is hex `61 62 63 C39F`

Comment: I have no idea where it came from , but this is what I see when I read the query results with `mysql_fetch_row()`. The script is coming from Windows. Running the query in mySQL Workbench does not produce "abcß" in both Windows and Linux.

Comment: also I can't be sure it is encoded as UTF-8. Script comes from Windows and I ran it on Linux copy of Workbench connected to server running on Linux.

Comment: How was the INSERT originally performed?

Comment: that was `CREATE TABLE();` and not an `INSERT INTO;`. I just send the script from Windows to Linux box, loaded it into mySQL Workbench and executed. And doing the Workbench query I am seeing the big accentric "A" symbol.

Comment: question edited with the results I see in the mySQL Workbench.

Comment: Oh, you mean `CREATE TABLE t (...) SELECT ...`?  That is, the `SELECT` is suspect.

Comment: Nope, that was just `CREATE TABLE abcß(<some fields>);`. Then after the script finished doing `SELECT` from EDIT3 does not produce the same name.

Comment: Aha!  A table name, not data.  You typed that directly into Workbench?  What were the charaset-related settings for Workbench at the time?  And `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%'`

Comment: I didn't type it in. It is part of the bigger script for database creation exported from SQLite on Windows. Then the script was sent from Windows to Linux, opened in Workbench and executed. I will post the output later today when I come home. But the Workbench was just installed - I didn't tweak it in any way.

Comment: Can you get a hex dump of the script.  Need to find out whether the problem comes _before_ or _after_ that.  Then continue to isolate it.